# Python/BS - Getting URLs from html files stored in a directory, save to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a folder full of html files, and I'm trying to scrape all the urls that are leading to different pages, and save these urls to a CSV file.

I've read around here on Stackoverflow, and tried to modify a code I have used earlier, but no success. Python is going through the files, but it fails to get the data I need.

I wrote my first Python code a month ago, so I'm still a rookie and I hope someone out there can help!

The code I've been using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib2
import os

def processData( pageFile ):
    f = open(pageFile, "r")
    page = f.read()
    f.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    urldata = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True})

    urls = []


    for html in urldata:
        html = soup('<body><a href="123">qwe</a><a href="456">asd</a></body>')

    csvfile = open('url.csv', 'ab')
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for url in zip(urls):
        writer.writerow([url])

    csvfile.close()

dir = "myurlfiles"

csvFile = "url.csv"

csvfile = open(csvFile, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow(["URLS"])
csvfile.close()

fileList = os.listdir(dir)

totalLen = len(fileList)
count = 1

for htmlFile in fileList:
    path = os.path.join(dir, htmlFile) # get the file path
    processData(path) # process the data in the file
    print "Processed '" + path + "'(" + str(count) + "/" + str(totalLen) + ")..." 
    count = count + 1
```

The urls are stored in the html code in the following way:

```
<div class="item" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="item_image" style="width: 180px; height: 125px;" id="image_255"><a href="https://silkroad6ownowfk.onion.to/items/200mg-high-quality-dmt" style="display: block; width: 180px; height: 125px;"></a></div>
  <div class="item_body">
    <div class="item_title"><a href="https://silkroad6ownowfk.onion.to/items/200mg-high-quality-dmt">200mg High Quality DMT</a></div>
    <div class="item_details">
      vendor: <a href="https://silkroad6ownowfk.onion.to/users/ringo-deathstarr">ringo deathstarr</a><br>
      ships from: United States<br>
      ships to: Worldwide
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item_price">
   <div class="price_big">฿0.031052</div>
    <a href="https://silkroad6ownowfk.onion.to/items/200mg-high-quality-dmt#shipping">add to cart</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to find all of the `html` files in the directory by `*.html` mask, find all links via `BeautifulSoup`'s `find_all()` and write them to the file (looks like you don't need `csv` module here at all):

```
import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


path = 'myurlfiles/*.html'

urls = []
for file_name in glob.iglob(path):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
        urls += [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a', {'href': True})]

with open("url.csv", "wb") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(urls))
```

Note that you don't need to read the file before passing it to [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup) constructor - it supports file-like objects also. Also, follow best practices and use `with` context manager while working with files.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! This worked fairly well, except that I got the text in the URLs, and not the full URLs? So not http://www.apples.com, but 'apples'.

Comment: @user3343907 ok, just change `link.text` to `link['href']`.